Displaying images with Detailview
I'm having some problems with the DetailView in django and sqlit3, I have tree options in my home page there you can chose 1 of 3 and you get a list of images this works but only the Studio option I can get Detailed views. thanks..
Link to site ahoogzand.com
Have 3 models "Studio, Street, Travel"
I'm not very good at this just picked up bits and pieces from the net but can't find any thing for my problem
    class Photo(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
        submitter = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Street(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='streetPhotos/')
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Travel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='travelPhotos/')
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

URLS.py

app_name = "photo"


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PhotoListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('studio/', StudioView.as_view(), name='studio'),
    path('street/', StreetView.as_view(), name='street'),
    path('travel/', TravelView.as_view(), name='travel'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag>/', PhotoTagListView.as_view(), name='tag'),
    path('studioDetail/<int:pk>/', StudioDetailView.as_view(), name='studioDetail'),
    path('streetDetail/<int:pk>/', StreetDetailView.as_view(), name='streetDetail'),
    path('travelDetail/<int:pk>/', TravelDetailView.as_view(), name='travelDetail'),
    path('photo/studioCreate/', StudioCreateView.as_view(), name='studioCreate'),
    path('photo/streetCreate/', StreetCreateView.as_view(), name='streetCreate'),
    path('photo/travelCreate/', StreetCreateView.as_view(), name='travelCreate'),
    path('photo/tripCreate/', TravelCreateView.as_view(), name='tripCreate'),
    path('photo/<int:pk>/update/', PhotoUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('photo/<int:pk>/delete/', PhotoDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]


Views.py

class StudioDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Photo
    template_name = 'photoApp/studioDetail.html'


class StreetDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Street
    template_name = 'photoApp/streetDetail.html'

class TravelDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Travel
    template_name = 'photoApp/travelDetail.html'



Share the corresponding models.

please [edit] the question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Think I found where the problem is...  ---
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [photo] ---
now I nead the solution of passing varible from one view to the next..

Found my problem was simple needed to add "context_object_name"
to the DetaleView..
class StreetDetailView(DetailView):
model = Street
template_name = 'photoApp/streetDetail.html'
context_object_name = 'photo'

And Now next problem ...
